# Retrieve Web Server Request URL in Application Server

Tags: url, servlets, web, httprequest

I have below scenario. I have a Application running in an App Server 
    behind a Web Server

```
Web Server   <--------------------------->   App Server
url: http://webserver                       url: http://appserver:7012
```

Now when I do a request.getRequestURL or URI in my Servlet Filter. 
    I get the App Server Url (http://appserver:7012) not the 
    Web Server Url(http://webserver).
    I need to get the Web Server url not App Server url. How do I get it ?
    Any suggestions on how do I go about it.

Thanks!!!
    SKR